# What is the TsLint rule name for breaking lambda expression arrow?

Tags: angular, typescript, tslint

I used the syntax with broken arrow like this.

```
const result = data.map( _ 
  => this.reallyLongExpressionSoBreakingArrowMakesSense(_));
```

Then I noticed that TsLint flagged the spot and gave me the following information.

> Line terminator not permitted before arrow. (ts1200)

I haven't found anything similar to it in my *tslint.json* so I went to [the docs](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/) to see what the actual name is. As far I can see, there's nothing corresponding to the message.

1. What is the TsLint rule corresponding to the message?
2. What is the point of *ts1200* in the parentheses after the message?

Comment: Seems to be a compatibility issue and not an actual rule that you can configure: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2282

Comment: I think the most correct answer is that this error is a Typescript error. Since Typescript compiler doesn't support break lines before =>. So that's why you can't just disable a tslint rule to bypass it. It's a Typescript Language rule. Not a TSLint one.

Comment: @EduardoJunior  I mean, I don't question your statement. I'm just questioning the sanity of the design. I can't see any technical reason for setting the lambda arrow here or there. In other languages, it's never been an issue, so I'm rather stumbled... What do you think?

Comment: Well, i think Typescript is an awesome language and you shouldn't like it less just because of this tiny thing. And there must be a reason for that. I just don't know what it is. But i agree with you  that shouldn't be a problem. I just don't thing this is a real big deal. But you are right to question it :) But maybe the Github TS repo is the right place to get the answer.

Comment: @EduardoJunior Oh, don't get me wrong - I thing TS is awesome and love using it. As for the tech reason, I claim there's none (based on the fact that it's semantically non-significant), unless someone bitchslaps me in the face with actual argument. I believe it's like so due to a contributor's taste (as discussed in the linked GitHub discussion) and that's hardly technical. But only speculating since I don't know the dude. I was just so chocked to discover that...   :)

Comment: Yeah, i see your point. And one strange thing to see is that, at the TS Playground, for exemple http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/. It shows the error but It compiles flawlessly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Seems like there is no tslint rule for that, only [ESLint](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/implicit-arrow-linebreak).
2. `ts1200` the code of the error. Check it [here](https://github.com/caitp/TypeScript/blob/02d356800f36ecd548641d993ab4b70359de2e70/src/compiler/diagnosticMessages.json#L624). Check the original pr [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/2283/files).

Comment: This is actually the most to-the-point'y answer I've seen in a very long time. I already accepted another answer so you're a bit late to the party. However, it stroke me as such a perfect, ninja style cut spot on perfect reply, I'm going to bounty you. And knowing that I'm a stingy duck harvesting the rep, it's a huge honor.   :)

Comment: Hmm... You'll have to remind me in 48 hours. Apparently, no bounty allowed the first two days.

Comment: Thank you. I love this community because of people like you.

Comment: ...and I have to wait for 23 hours and 59 seconds to award the bounty to you. Please, please, pretty please with cherry on top - do remind me.   :)

Comment: @KonradViltersten - Please note that it is never too late to change the accepted answer when a better one is proposed.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Good point. I usually feel reluctance to changing the accepted answers since the question is asked at a certain point of time and **that** answer tends to be the best answer. If there's a new tech allowing for a better answer, should we change the green check to the new one? Okay - but what if new tech renders the question not needed? It seems so inconsequential to keep in the latter but update in former case. However, I see your point in this instance, so I re-accepted. Still, I'm curious how you figure in regard to my aversion.

Answer (score 1):

[As contributors said](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2282), that this behavior is not fixed:

> I think it's unlikely anyone is using this syntax, since it's much
>   harder to read, but if it breaks apps then it might not be worth
>   fixing.

[In addition](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/2283):

> However, the problem I ran into when I tried to fix this was that it's
>   a real pain to work on the token-level in the checker. So I wonder if
>   the benefit of the idea is actually worth the cost.

**UPDATE:**

Try to make them `_ =>` on the same line, but the call of your method on the next line:

```
const result = data.map( _ => 
    this.reallyLongExpressionSoBreakingArrowMakesSense(_));
```

Comment: It looks like if you're answering *how to fix the issue to comply with the rule*. In such case, you've got it all wrong. I'm asking how to fit the rule to my syntax. We're using a strategy where a broken line (of any kind) continues by an operator. So it's *some-some-break-**plus**-some-some*.

Comment: Yeah, I just read a comment from @EduardoJunior too. I'm kind of flabbergasted that it is an issue (since other languages don't have the problem putting lambda arrow on next line) and see no logical reason for that to be an obstacle. Also, but that's a matter of taste, I strongly disagree that it's harder to read nor that it's uncommon to have an operator of broken-up statement at the beginning. It's actually very clear that it's not a new statement. But like I said - it's a matter of taste and people can go ji'had on those things so let's not go there, haha. But the part with tech reason?

Comment: @KonradViltersten The part of tech reason could be *[However, the problem I ran into when I tried to fix this was that it's a real pain to work on the token-level in the checker. So I wonder if the benefit of the idea is actually worth the cost.](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/2283)*

Comment: I want to stress that I fully understand the importance of not surprising the next guy at the code. And I also want to clarify that the matter is of rather slight significance in relation to the world's burdens. Now, having that disclaimed, I need to point out that the quote is **not** a technical reason but an individual deficiency and lack of urgency on the developers account.   :)

Answer (score -1):

I solved this by extracting fat arrow and expression before that by pushing them into one line

Comment: How is that a solution to begin with? I don't want to keep them on the same line for obvious reasons. I'm not asking what the linting message means. Please elaborate how this is aligns with the actual question being asked.